# Searching for my Pygame version

Tags: python, pygame

I am having trouble finding **pygame** version **2.7.5** for my python 2.7.5 software. All help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on windows [this](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi) will work for you.  There is no version `2.7.5` but rather pygame version `1.9.2` that is made for python `2.7.5`.